# ppa essential for ElementaryOS

Tags: ppa, repositories

I want to have the repositories is essential in my system. 
can someone give me a list with the most safe and needed.

thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need is already inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

You don't need any extra PPA. If you want some interesting programs you can check the following:

- [Just installed EOS on my Chromebook. Working great! Just wondering about the best tweaks or programs that I may not know about](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/3m6gg1/just_installed_eos_on_my_chromebook_working_great/)
- [Apps for elementary](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/apps/)
- [Which apps would you install after installing loki, to make it more awesome?](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/51y9wa/which_apps_would_you_install_after_installing/)

But be careful! Make sure the program you are trying to install works on your elementary OS version.

Comment: exact! for that reason I want to leave the PPA exenciales to the system and delete those that I don't need. 
in any case I can re-enter them if the dependencies are needed for any application.

someone can show the APP that come by default when you perform the installation of ElementaryOS for the first time?


thanks

Comment: By default you have `elementary.list` and `patches.list` inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. You also have `/etc/apt/sources.list` by default.

If you installed things like `google-chrome` or manually added a PPA, you would also have their corresponding `.list` file inside `sources.list.d/` and you shouldn't delete those files. Because you need them to receive updates for those apps.  If all you want is to have only the default packages you better just install elementary OS again. That is going to be much faster than deleting packages one by one.